# How to query 2 identical tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've been looking all over for a answer to this question.

I got 2 mysql tables that have a identical setup

```
table1 [id] [customer_name] [project_number] [project_type]

table2 [id] [customer_name] [project_number] [project_type]
```

All I want to do with these is to order them by [customer_name] and then list them in a while loop, this is supposed to be displayed in a common dropdown select field.
The constant difference between these tables is the [project_type] which is set to 0 in 'table 1' and 1 in 'table 2'

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: You should look into UNION.

Comment: so use a union, and sort the results of the union. and in the bigger picture, why have two tables in the first place? if they're separated by the value of a particular field, there's no point in having each copy of that value in its own dedicated table.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Comment: Perfect! that did the trick. Thanks guys :) Reason why I can't use 1 table is that these are 2 separate system, but they are running on the same server, I made a second table to avoid mixing them. they only have this 1 function in common.